# iptables crippling downlink on CentOS 4.x VMs

Tags: centos, iptables, slow-connection

With iptables service running, downlink traffic is less than 500KB/sec.  When turning off iptables, downlink traffic is around 25MB/sec.

Uplink is fine.

Any ideas as to why this might be occurring or how I can troubleshoot?

Here is the iptables config:

```
# Firewall configuration written by system-config-securitylevel
# Manual customization of this file is not recommended.
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:RH-Firewall-1-INPUT - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT
-A FORWARD -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p 50 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p 51 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p udp --dport 5353 -d 224.0.0.251 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 161 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 162 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 1521 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 1521 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8081 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 2176 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 2177 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 2180 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 6080 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 9999 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5222 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

Comment: What type of traffic?

Comment: just doing simple wget of an iso file.

http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/gparted/gparted-live-stable/0.9.1-1/gparted-live-0.9.1-1.iso

Answer (score 0):

Unless the CPU is incredible slow, can you compare that the iptable-save has the same output as the one listed? Also check the incoming traffic.

Comment: CPU idle time remains near 100% during the download.  Live iptables is exactly the same as config.

Comment: An addendum to this problem...

When starting the iptables service via an SSH connection, the SSH connection is broken every time.  That in itself is odd, but even more-so is that it that the connection isn't broken right away.  The connection breaks after a certain amount of output is pushed to the SSH session.

Example:

/etc/init.d/iptables restart
{Can now sit idle for any period of time with no effect.}
ps -ef
{Just this little bit of output causes my session to terminate.}